# Jenkins pipeline - generate parameters for pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy, parameters, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to do something like:

```
def myParams = [string(name: 'PARAM19', defaultValue: 'value19'),
                string(name: 'PARAM20', defaultValue: 'value20')]
pipeline {
    agent any
    parameters { myParams }
    stages {
        stage('Example') {
            steps {
                echo("ok")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

how to use defined list as parameters in job

Answer (score 1):

Just do the below.

```
properties([
    parameters([
        string(name: 'Cloud', defaultValue: 'AWS', description: 'Cloud Type')
    ])
])

pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage("Hello") {
            steps {
                echo "Building Something"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`*` in groovy allows to get every element out of a list and since in `parameters{}` you don't put a list but just the elements in it, you should try `parameters{ *myParams }`